# Column Mapping in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a web application that imports data from an Excel file to my Gridview. The data from the GridView can then be saved to SQL Database on rowbasis (using checkbox).But i  have a problem importing Excel files with different column names than the SQL Database. Can this be done?
following is the code to import the data from the excel file to the GridView(in button click event)

```
DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();                
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from Sheet1$]", oledbconn);
OleDbDataAdapter dr = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", oledbconn)
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
dr.Fill(ds, "Select");
DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Select"];
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
lblresult.Text = "Record Uploaded";
```

The code i am using to  save data to sql table is-

```
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Deepesh;Initial Catalog=ExcelDB;Integrated Security=SSPI");
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("checkselect");
        //Label lblid = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblid");
        Label lblname = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblname");
        Label lbllogin = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lbllogin");
        Label lblemail = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lblemail");
        DropDownList lbldesignation = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("DropDownList");
        TextBox lbladdress = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("TextBox2");


        if (chk.Checked == true)
        {
            cn.Open();


            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employee(Name,Login_Id,Email_Id,Designation,Address) VALUES(@lblname,@lbllogin,@lblemail,@lbldesignation,@lbladdress)", cn);
               // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lblid",Convert.ToInt32(lblid.ToString()));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lblname", lblname.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lbllogin", lbllogin.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lblemail", lblemail.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lbldesignation", lbldesignation.Text.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lbladdress", lbladdress.Text.ToString());





                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cn.Close();
        }
        lblresult.Text = "Data Saved";

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what is the problem? show your code please?

Comment: please add pieces of code

Comment: i have edited my question and added the code snippets,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. I think we need to check with number of columns and attributes of gridview control.

Comment: can you please tell me in detail which attribute exactly.
i have an excel file with foll columns ..
name,login_id,email_id,designation and address but i want to import a file with column names say -
name, email , location,designation,username.
if i try it with the code i m using it just shows up the gridview with a single empty row ...